# How to customize the size of a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to force a UITabBarController to be a size less than the full Window size on an iPhone? I noticed if I change its frame size & origin that works until it seems to resize itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off by creating a customTabBarController and setting

```
 -(UITabBar *) tabBar { 
return nil; 
}
```

And thereupon add your custom TabBar in `viewDidLoad` of customTabBarController. Here you could have the frame, background color, autoresize of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! This is great information. However, I would like to adjust the size of the entire UITabBarController - not just the tab bar buttons. Do you know how that could be done?

Comment: With the help of the evangelist I found this can be done as long as the view is not the base/main view of the window.